# toolbar alternative of splitactionbar

Tags: android

The android documentation about split action bar is not supported anymore and doesnt expalin how to achieve the below image.

I need your help ( a good example or SO answer) on how to achieve the below image:

[image]

I tried this but did'nt work

```
 @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Toolbar tb=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        tb.inflateMenu(R.menu.actions);
        tb.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return(onOptionsItemSelected(item));
          }
        });

        return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
      }
```

Comment: Please Highlight what part is to be achieved? is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mlyhn.png) part required?

Comment: @ArshadAli in the code that i added inthe question , i was able to achieve it but i didnt know to display activity 1 and activity 2 and the icons on the action bar disapeared

Comment: Try this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: @KishuDroid great tutorial . thanks

Comment: @Moudiz : Glad to help you. :-)